# mysql 5.6 change lower_case_table_names won't work

Tags: mysql, tablename

1. My os is windows 7 and mysql version is 5.6.20;
2. I opened `my.ini`, add `lower_case_table_names=2` as a line below `[mysqld]`, save and quit;
3. Selected with `show variables like '%lower_case_table_names%';` and the request is `lower_case_table_names   2`,
4. I alter a table named `Article`, clicked button 'apply' the workbench show message "The server is configured with lower_case_table_names=1, which only allows  lowercase characters in schema and table names. the object will be crated as 'article'"
5. Click button "ok", the workbench show table name is `article`,

All above, the setting is not working, hope someone tell my why and how to fix it

Comment: Restarting mysql service should fix it.

Comment: Read more about restarting MySQL service here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-start-service.html

Comment: i restarted and it's not work

Answer (score 0):

lower_case_table_names can only be configured when initializing the server. Changing the lower_case_table_names setting after the server is initialized is prohibited.